# Json decode error

Tags: java, json

My code parse string is:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse("{\"id\":\"3578273\",\"username\":\"thangdayhpv\"}");
id = (String) json.get("id");
username = (String) json.get("username");
```

This code run successfully.

But this:

```
data = "{\"id\":\"3578273\",\"username\":\"thangdayhpv\"}";
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(data);
id = (String) json.get("id");
username = (String) json.get("username");
```

does not work. The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
>
> at bg.mappingmingid.userinfo.GetUserInfo$DataFormat.formatJson(GetUserInfo.java:82)
>
> at bg.mappingmingid.userinfo.GetUserInfo.main(GetUserInfo.java:39)

Comment: @Nishant The data types of "id" and "username" are irrelevant.  The issue is a string being cast to JSONObject.

Comment: I think you did not specify the data types for id and username

Comment: @Vulcan There seems no difference in case #1 and case #2... so I am wondering what could be the reason... I guess I meant a request for complete code

Comment: cldo, could you please add to your question what is line 82 (the line where the top element in the error stack trace is).

Comment: Actually, wait a second.  What JSON library are you using?  I assumed [this one](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/source/browse/trunk/src/org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser.java?r=73) but at second glance, `JSONParser#parse` requires a `Reader` as the parameter, and you are passing a String.

Comment: Thank for reply.i resolve by replace character '\' in var data = {\"id\":\"3578273\",\"username\":\"thangdayhpv\"}.Thanks again.